# Can I supress the loading dialogs in Java Web Start?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

I'm trying to put together a Java Webstart app, but don't want it to display the Webstart splash screen, or "downloading app" boxes. Is there any way I can turn them off? (I'm fine with it displaying the Permissions Request box, but nothing else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the -nosplash option.

Place this:

```
<argument>-nosplash</argument>
```

in your JNLP document.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use your on startup image:

MyProject1.0
    My Company.
    
    Application Launcher For MyProject1.0
    
  
  ....

Answer (score 0):

Note, that for production use you might want the visual feedback to users, to avoid the "It doesn't work today" (where a big update must be downloaded over a slow line resulting in long startup times).

Comment: What I'd like to do is to have the feedback be in my page instead, the only reason I'm even using WebStart is because it loads in a separate process and hence won't hang the browser.